# how can i remove the middle of an image in photoshop 7

Tags: adobe-photoshop

i have an image and i want to remove a piece of the middle to make the overall image smaller width.

Is there anyway where i can select a section in the middle and it removes that section and collapses from the left and right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really ought to know how to manipulate selections to get *anywhere* in Photoshop.

1. Select the side of the image you
   want to move, using the Rectangular
   Marquee Tool.
2. Cut (CTRL+X)
3. Paste (CTRL+V)
4. Use the Move Tool to move the new
   layer into place (it should snap into place horizontally)

Comment: of course . . just had a brain freeze